# Field ... is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#

I have the following `HandleErrorModule` class:

```
public sealed class HandleErrorModule : IHttpModule {
    private static ILogger _logger;
    private static CustomErrorsSection _section;
    private static Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, String> _views;

    private static CustomErrorsSection CustomErrorsSection { 
      get { 
        if (_section != null) 
          return _section;
        else 
          return WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("system.web/customErrors") as CustomErrorsSection; 
      } 
    }

    private static ILogger Logger { 
      get { return (_logger != null) ? _logger : ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>(); }
    }

    private static Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, String> Views { 
      get { 
        if (_views != null) 
          return _views;
        else
          return new Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, String> { { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "NotFound_" }, { HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal_" } }; 
       } 
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application) {

       // Handle error code.
       // Here I access CustomErrorsSection, Logger and Views properties

    }
```

In get the warning in:

> Field 'HandleErrorModule._views' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
>   Field 'HandleErrorModule._section' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
>   Field 'HandleErrorModule._logger' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warnings are pretty clear.  You never assign any values to those variables, so they'll always be null.  You "fix this" by either assigning values to the variables or removing them entirely since they're never used.

Comment: For example, `_views` is `private` and none of your `private` methods or properties ever assigns a value to it. Because it's `private` the compiler knows that no other code has an opportunity to set its value either. Thus the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted those static properties to lazily initialize the objects. The way you did it though, they never set the private fields, but keep on creating new objects. So you probably wanted to do it like this instead:

```
private static Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, String> Views
{
    get
    {
        // when the private field is null, initialize the value
        if (_views == null)
        {
            _views = new Dictionary<HttpStatusCode, String> {
                    { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "NotFound_" },
                    { HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal_" } };
        }

        // and always return the private field
        return _views;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty clear form the message. None of the members are assigned values anywhere. The properties where they are used are get only.

Looking the kind of code and presumed usage, I would suggest a parameterized constructor that can set values for these fields.